# Flatten columns with lists in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, functional-programming, flatten

I have a dataframe with some columns in lists and I would like to flatten these list columns.
Below is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': ['abcd3', 'd4fs3'],
    'col_2': ['vfce157', 'dfde28'],
    'col_3': [['id_1','id_2'],['id_4','id_6','id_7']],
    'col_4': [['p_1','p_2'],['p_3','p_5','p_0']],
    'col_5': [['d_1','d_2'],['d_4','d_7','d_8']]
})
df
```

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd3 | vfce157 | [id_1,id_2] | [p_1,p_2] | [d_1,d_2] |
| d4fs3 | dfde28 | [id_4,id_6,id_7] | [p_3,p_5,p_0] | [d_4,d_7,d_8] |

The result expected:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd3 | vfce157 | id_1 | p_1 | d_1 |
| abcd3 | vfce157 | id_2 | p_2 | d_2 |
| d4fs3 | dfde28 | id_4 | p_3 | d_4 |
| d4fs3 | dfde28 | id_6 | p_5 | d_7 |
| d4fs3 | dfde28 | id_7 | p_0 | d_8 |

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Can you share the dataframe as python object, so that anyone who wants to work with your data can easily copy and paste.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) Pandas method

`df.explode(['col3', 'col4', 'col5'])` should do the trick

Comment: It works in a simple and elegant way. Thank you @christospitsi !!